# How I can access to values inside of this object returned from an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, object

[Image with the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff97L.png)

I want to access and print info of the object "hits"

this is my code:

```
export async function fetchData(searchValue) {
    await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchValue}&app_id=${apiId}&app_key=${apiKey}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((res) => {return res;});
}
```

Comment: You need to resolve the promise first... post the relevant code if you want help...

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the data directly from that function use

```js
export async function fetchData(searchValue) {
  return await fetch(
    `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchValue}&app_id=${apiId}&app_key=${apiKey}`
  )
    .then((response) => response.json());
}
```

Now when calling the method either use async/await or `.then` to log

```js
// async/await (inside of an async function)
const result = await fetchData('something');
console.log(result.hits);

// `.then`
fetchData('something').then(result => console.log(result.hits));
```